# Debuging a PhoneGap Build app with facebook connected on Ripple

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Honestly, I'm completely lost. I including the android cordova.js (2.0.0) and facebook-js-sdk.js files, but when I make a FB.init call I get an popup window that says that cordiva is missing  org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect.getLoginStatus.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to include those files in your project. Simply place

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

in the head of the html pages you have and place

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="..." />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="..." />
</gap:plugin>
```

in your config.xml. When you build with phonegap-build it will include the appropriate files into your project for you. Read [this](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1) and FULLY read [this](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/blob/master/README.md) ensuring you pay attention to the part titled "Facebook Requirements and Set-Up".

You will not be able to debug this with Ripple because it is using plugin files that you do not have access to (unless RIM tied Ripple into the Adobe resources...).

If you continue to experiece problems, please post some code of what you have attempted so we can continue to assist.